# Jenkins Build Number in power shell script

Tags: powershell, curl, jenkins, slack-api

On running the power shell scrip

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#personal", "username": "Jenkins", "text": "Building $env:BUILD_NUMBER", "icon_emoji": ":computer:"}' https://xxxxxx.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=aseaUO
```

or

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel": "#personal-notification", "username": "Jenkins", "text": "Building ${BUILD_NUMBER}", "icon_emoji": ":computer:"}' https://xxxxxx.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=aseaUO
```

The {BUILD_NUMBER} is not getting replaced by actual build number in the curl payload

--Edit
I noticed that my sh script is invoking git\bin\sh.exe. is that a problem?

On trying one of the comments below
    curl -X POST --data-urlencode $('payload={0}"channel": "#personal", "username": "Jenkins", "text": "Building {1}", "icon_emoji": ":computer:"{2}' -f "{", $env:rohan) "}" https://xxxxxx.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=aseaUO I get

[image]

On directly trying to run the script on PS terminal I get

[image]

Comment: Buildnumber is defined in global environment variable  `env:` or in psvariable `variable:` ? Try with this: `${env:BUILD_NUMBER}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the entire expression is wrapped in single quotes, so PowerShell won't evaluate your `$env:BUILD_NUMBER` expression.

Use a string formatting expression. NB you also have to use formatting to keep the { } chars out of the base expression to avoid runtime errors.

```
 curl -X POST --data-urlencode $('payload={0}"channel": "#personal", "username": "Jenkins", "text": "Building {1}", "icon_emoji": ":computer:"{2}' -f "{", $env:BUILD_NUMBER) ,"}") https://xxxxxx.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=aseaUO
```

Comment: No doesn't solve it. Getting "error formatting  string"  error

Comment: Agh. Maybe the curly braces are screwing with the positional formatting.

Comment: @walid is on the right track with breaking down the curl arguments into an array.  If the curly braces play havoc with the -f operator the you will have to build the string up bit by bit or use lots of escaping

Comment: I think the problem is elsewhere. I have edited the post with more information. Hopefully this will show your expert eyes where it actually is.

Comment: My bad. I misssed the ) after the -f  and before the url

Comment: And the commaafter the env

Comment: On reflection, why are you even running curl from powershell when you can use invoke-webrequest

Comment: Thats exactly how I resolved it. But it was the second time i got stuck in shell like this so posted. curious why it behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

few problem in your code, first the quotes ( variable in ps not expanded in quote) second the (stupid) parameter...try with this if not worked change Build_Number to ${BUILD_NUMBER}

```
$param = @()
$param = "-X POST"
$param += "--data-urlencode 'payload={""channel"": ""#personal"", ""username"": ""Jenkins"", ""text"": ""Building ${env:BUILD_NUMBER}", ""icon_emoji"": "":computer:""}'"
$param += "https://xxxxxx.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=aseaUO"
$curl $param
```

Or

```
$param = ''
$param = "-X POST"
$param += "--data-urlencode 'payload={""channel"": ""#personal"", ""username"": ""Jenkins"", ""text"": ""Building ${env:BUILD_NUMBER}", ""icon_emoji"": "":computer:""}'"
$param += "https://xxxxxx.slack.com/services/hooks/incoming-webhook?token=aseaUO"
$curl $param
```

Comment: I didn't mention above but there is one more strange problem with my original command.
- I cannot run it directly on Power Shell. I get error
    unmatched closed bracket at pos 42

But when i put it in a .sh file and call it it invokes a terminal (not PS) window and runs. I never got around figuring out why that happens.

In your case the variable is perfectly getting parsed now. But my old error is back. Even though i am running it from a .sh file the terminal fires up and shows a message which is too quick to read before it disappears and it doesn't work.